# Trying to assign specific chars as a variable in C...giving me some difficulty

Tags: c, variables, compiler-errors, char

So I am trying to assign a char variable with the value "#" or "%" or "!" and if the variable does not have that value, I am prompting the user with an error.  While compiling, I am getting the error "error: comparison between pointer and integer".  Now, my code where the error is happening is this segment:

```
    if (((a == !) || (a == %) || (a == #)) && (w > 0 && h > 0)) {
    //do something
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why an error is coming up here.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `==` means comparison. Character literals must be enclosed in single quites, e.g. `a == '!'` . An assignment would be `a = '!';`

Comment: You do know that `!` is not a character literal, it's the logical not operator. However, `'!'` *is* a character literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chars in C must be surrounded by single quotes:

```
if (((a == '!') || (a == '%') || (a == '#')) && (w > 0 && h > 0))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had double quotes before and that wasn't working...this hadn't crossed my mind.  Thank you!

Comment: What's a Simple quote?